# Match two tables (Detail table to Subtotal table) while identify non-matching items in detail table

Tags: python, pandas

I have to match summary/subtotal table with details table, while identify non-matching items in details table.

Since the time differences between details record and subtotal records deviates significantly (+/-), the method i applied using pandas merge_asof() was not good enough even-though it matches based on a given timedelta value it will not check whether the amounts are equal between two tables. 
Is there a way to code, considering each value in subtotal table, calculate subtotals from detail table, and if matches then move into next item in subtotal table and start subtotaling from the next item in details table.
Appreciate if someone can help on this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

subtotal = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Date':['21/09/2018  17:45:27','21/09/2018  19:10:24','21/09/2018  21:42:03'],
                             'Amount':[2000,3000,6000],
                             'Ref':[1,2,3]},columns=['Date', 'Amount', 'Ref'])

detail = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Date':['21/09/2018  17:37:05','21/09/2018  17:56:22','21/09/2018  17:56:53','21/09/2018  18:54:56','21/09/2018 19:12:56','21/09/2018 19:15:30 ','21/09/2018 21:35:59','21/09/2018  21:36:20','21/09/2018 21:43:32 '],
                             'Amount':[1000,500,500,1000,3000,12000,1000,2000,3000]},
                                columns=['Date', 'Amount'])

subtotal['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(subtotal['Date'])
detail['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(detail['Date'])

# Code i tried with pandas .merge_asof()

subtotal_sorted = subtotal.sort_values(by='Date')
detail_sorted = detail.sort_values(by='Date') 

subtotal_sorted.index = subtotal_sorted['Date']
detail_sorted.index = detail_sorted['Date']

tol = pd.Timedelta('15 minute')
result = pd.merge_asof(left=detail_sorted,right=subtotal_sorted, right_index=True,left_index=True,direction='nearest',tolerance=tol)
```

"I'm expecting a resultant table similar to this." But just using pandas mergeasof() does not match the subtotal values. So i have to look into a another method.

```
Ref DateTime             Value       Result     Ref_1   DateTime_1          Value_1
1   09/21/2018 17:37     1,000.00    Index1     1       09/21/2018 17:45    2000
2   09/21/2018 17:56     500.00      Index1     1       09/21/2018 17:45    2000
3   09/21/2018 17:56     500.00      Index1     1       09/21/2018 17:45    2000
4   09/21/2018 18:54     1,000.00    Index2     2       09/21/2018 19:10    3000
5   09/21/2018 19:12     2,000.00    Index2     2       09/21/2018 19:10    3000
6   09/21/2018 19:15     12,000.00   No Match           
7   09/21/2018 21:35     1,000.00    Index3     3       09/21/2018 21:42    6000
8   09/21/2018 21:36     2,000.00    Index3     3       09/21/2018 21:42    6000
9   09/21/2018 21:43     3,000.00    Index3     3       09/21/2018 21:42    6000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is one of those problems where it is not going to be easy to get an exact match on everything. Anyway I took a shot at it.

First let us define a function doing the merge. This is pretty much the same thing you did already, only with the addition of summing over `Amount_detail` for all matching subtotals, keepoing only the rows where the sums match.

```
def merge(subtotal, detail, tol):

    subtotal.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)
    detail.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True) 

    # We merge using merge_asof as before
    result = pd.merge_asof(left=detail,right=subtotal, on='Date',
                           direction='nearest',tolerance=tol)
    # We total amount_detail over the matching ref
    result['sum_amount_detail'] = result.groupby(['Ref'])['Amount_detail'].transform('sum')

    # If sum_amount_detail == Amount_subtotal we have a match!!
    match = result[result['sum_amount_detail'] == result['Amount_subtotal']]
    # Otherwise... no
    no_match = result[result['sum_amount_detail'] != result['Amount_subtotal']]

    detail_match = match[['Date', 'Amount_detail', 'Ref']].copy()
    detail_no_match = no_match[['Date', 'Amount_detail']].copy()
    subtotal_match = subtotal[subtotal['Ref'].isin(detail_match['Ref'].unique())].copy()
    subtotal_no_match = subtotal[~subtotal['Ref'].isin(detail_match['Ref'].unique())].copy()

    return detail_match, subtotal_match, detail_no_match, subtotal_no_match
```

Now using this function with your original criteria (15 min tolerance)

```
import pandas as pd

subtotal = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Date':['21/09/2018  17:45:27','21/09/2018  19:10:24','21/09/2018  21:42:03'],
                             'Amount_subtotal':[2000,3000,6000],
                             'Ref':[1,2,3]},columns=['Date', 'Amount_subtotal', 'Ref'])

detail = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Date':['21/09/2018  17:37:05','21/09/2018  17:56:22','21/09/2018  17:56:53','21/09/2018  18:54:56','21/09/2018 19:12:56','21/09/2018 19:15:30 ','21/09/2018 21:35:59','21/09/2018  21:36:20','21/09/2018 21:43:32 '],
                             'Amount_detail':[1000,500,500,1000,3000,12000,1000,2000,3000]},
                                columns=['Date', 'Amount_detail'])
subtotal['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(subtotal['Date'])
detail['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(detail['Date'])

tol = pd.Timedelta('15 minute')
detail_match, subtotal_match, detail_no_match, subtotal_no_match = merge(subtotal, detail, tol)
```

This works okey except that there is one obvious flaw, and that is that the subtotal happening at `2018-09-21 19:10:24` (3000) is not included. This is because it also mathced with another value so the total overshoot out subtotal.

One workaround is to do the merge in a loop where we keep increasing the tolerance… that way we first get the closest matches... and then the matches getting ever further away. Its not pretty but it works.

```
tolerances = [pd.Timedelta('5 minute'), pd.Timedelta('10 minute'), pd.Timedelta('15 minute')]

subtotal_no_match = subtotal.copy()
detail_no_match = detail.copy()

detail_list = []
subtotal_list = []

for tol in tolerances:

    detail_match, subtotal_match, detail_no_match, subtotal_no_match = merge(subtotal_no_match, detail_no_match, tol)
    if len(detail_match) > 0:
        detail_list.append(detail_match)
        subtotal_list.append(subtotal_match)
    if len(subtotal_no_match)==0:
        # We have matched everything in subtotal
        break

detail_final = pd.concat(detail_list)
subtotal_final = pd.concat(subtotal_list)
```

```
detail_final
Out[5]: 
                 Date  Amount_detail  Ref
4 2018-09-21 19:12:56           3000  2.0
5 2018-09-21 21:35:59           1000  3.0
6 2018-09-21 21:36:20           2000  3.0
7 2018-09-21 21:43:32           3000  3.0
0 2018-09-21 17:37:05           1000  1.0
1 2018-09-21 17:56:22            500  1.0
2 2018-09-21 17:56:53            500  1.0


subtotal_final
Out[6]: 
                 Date  Amount_subtotal  Ref
1 2018-09-21 19:10:24             3000    2
2 2018-09-21 21:42:03             6000    3
0 2018-09-21 17:45:27             2000    1
```